# Open chrome:// protocol from terminal

Tags: google-chrome

I'm having trouble with starting chrome from command prompt with URL argument protocol `chrome://` (example: `chrome.exe chrome://settings`). The result is a new chrome window with blank page. Other protocols (file, http, https, etc.) work. Is there any workaround to start protocol `chrome://` from terminal?